# Show that the three statements $A \subseteq B$, $A \cup B=B$ and $A \cap B = A$ are logically equivalent. [Tao's Analysis I]

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

This question is from Tao's Analysis I and has got me stumped for a while. Even though, it's intuitive that the three statements are equivalent, when it came to writing a rigorous proof using mathematical logic, I flunked. Could please help me verify my proof?

> Let $A$, $B$ be sets. Show that the three statements $A\subseteq B$, $A \cup B=B$ and $A \cap B = A$ are logically equivalent.

***Proof.*** (My informal attempt).

(a) $1 \iff 2.$

We are given that $A \subseteq B$. We are interested to show that $A \cup B = B$.

($\Rightarrow$ direction)

Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A \cup B$. Then, atleast of the possibilities $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ hold. If $x \in A$, then $x \in B$, since $A \subseteq B$. If $x \in B$, then we are done. In both possibilities, $x$ belongs to $B$. So, $(A \cup B) \subseteq B$.

($\Leftarrow$ direction)

The converse is also true, since for any set $A$, we have $B \subseteq (B \cup A)$.

$\therefore$ $A \cup B = B.$

(b) $2 \iff 3.$

We are given that $A \cup B = B$. This means that $A \subseteq B$. We are interested to show that $A \cap B = A$.

($\Rightarrow$  direction)

Let $x$ be an arbitrary element in $A \cap B$. Then, both the propositions $x \in A$ and $x in B$ are true. Since, $A \subseteq B$, $x \notin (B\setminus A)$. For if $x \in (B \setminus A)$, then $x \in B$, but $x \notin A$, so $x\notin A \cup B$. Thus, $x \in A$. So, $(A \cap B) \subseteq A$.

($\Leftarrow$ direction)

The set $A \cap B := \{x:(x \in A)\land(x \in B)\}.$

If $x \in A$, then both the propositions $(x \in A)$ and $(x \in B)$ hold, since additionally $(x \in A) \implies (x \in B)$ when $A$ is a subset of $B$. So, $A \subseteq (A \cap B).$

$\therefore$ $A \cap B = A$.

(c) $3 \iff 1.$

I am not exactly sure how to proceed, so any hint would help. I was wondering if assuming a that $A$ contains elements which are not in $B$ leads me to a contradiction.

Comment: In a) you have only shown 1.$\implies$ 2. but not $2.\implies 1$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, the book already proves that lemma. However, I can write, if $x \in B$, the proposition $(x \in A)\lor (x \in B)$ holds. Hence, $x \in (A \cup B)$. Will that suffice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. $A \subseteq B$
2. $A \cup B=B$.
3. $A \cap B=A$.

1 implies 2: Assume 1. To show that $A \cup B \subseteq B$, let $x \in A \cup B$. If $x \in B$ we're done. If $x \in A$ then $x \in B$ by 1. So always $x \in B$ and 2. has been shown, as the other inclusion $B \subseteq A \cup B$ is trivial.

2 implies 3: Assume 2. To see 3. we only need to show $A \subseteq A \cap B$, as the other inclusion is again trivial. So let $x \in A$. This means $x \in A \cup B=B$ by 2, so $x \in B$ too and $x \in A \cap B$.

3 implies 1: Assume 3. Let $x \in A$. Then by 3. $x \in A \cap B$ so $x \in B$ in particular. This shows 1.

Going in circles for such equivalences is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

$$A\cap B=A\iff (A\cap B\subseteq A)\land (A\subseteq A\cap B)$$
$$A\cup B\subseteq B\;\;\land\;\;A\cap B\subseteq A, \;\;\;\;\;\;A\overset{?}\subseteq A\cap B$$
$$\text{if so, then, by the transitivity of the relation}\subseteq$$
$$A\subseteq A\cap B \land A\cap B\subseteq B\implies A\subseteq B$$
$$A\cap B=A\iff A\subseteq B\iff A\cup B=B$$

Hope this helps a bit. (: